# Getting receive pipeline error information in BAM

Tags: exception, biztalk, biztalk-bam

I have two orchestrations One of them is used as an error handler for the other orchestration, and is getting failed messages from it. I have set this up in BAM. The problem is when a file fails in the receive port I don't get any useful information in the Activity Search. Only that something has been registered. Data ex from BAM:

> ActivityID:    2738a492-04c7-4887-9ff3-6902f435bda4
>   ErrorCode:
>   ErrorDesc:
>   Filename:
>   Progress Error:     Handled
>   TransactionId:
>   rcvPort:
>   sndPort:

In the tracking profiler I use the properties from the errorReporter. Ex ErrorReport.FailureCode. The file gets moved as it should by the Error handler orchestration.

Does someone now what I'm doing wrong?

Is it possible to get any information when a file fails in the receive stage?

Mostly I need the filename and the error code/desc. (the Progress Error is a progress activity I have created).

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. For some reason I couldn't trace it to bam if I made progress dimension for the messages. When I just stored the plain data it worked ok.